# Firebase Blob storage security around download url

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Base on other question I figured out that there is no security around the `download URL` generated by firebase blob storage.

By no security I mean when a user has the URL they can share it with others.
I  understand that if someone shares the link they can also share the file but there is a big difference here, if I have a 1 hr video on blob storage then it will make difference.

1. It's much easier to share URL than downloading 1 hr video and share with others
2. when they share the URL they are using my resources while they have not paid for it

anyone can suggest a pattern to work around the problem and make sure the user has permission to accessing the file?

Comment: If I am working on a project which has files with big sizes, it will only take couple hours for my competitor to take my business down by downloading one huge file million times, and I have to pay for all those downloads to Firebase. (I still have to use download URL in the website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your users to have permission to download the content, then simply don't generate a download URL, and control access through [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) and the [server-side security rules of Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/). In this scenario you'd use the API to download the files. See the documentation for [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#download_to_a_local_file) and [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_to_a_local_file), this functionality is not available for the web.

Comment: I think I don't understand one critical point here. Is there a way to access the file without download URL? I just know you can download a file using the download URL. can you give me some hint, please?

Comment: Follow the documentation links in my answer, and you'll see how to read a file's contents from the server to a local file without a download URL. All you need to know is the path to the file in the bucket.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wish there was a way for web also because on the web it's much easier to access the URL.